# How to use a D-Link usb network adapter on debian

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I have a Debian (squeeze) desktop, and I need to use a D-Link 150 USB Wireless Network Adapter. So far I've done this:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2001:3c18 D-Link Corp.
...
```

After looking for a solution in google, I found that I needed to install the following package:

```
firmware-ralink_0.28+squeeze1_all.deb
```

I've installed it, but Debian doesn't want to find the adapter. When I run `lsmod`, I can't find what I'm supposed to find: `rt2870sta`... So I load it manually: `modprobe rt2870sta`... when I run `lsmod` now there are these new lines:

```
Module          Size   Used by
rt2870        360987   0
crc_ccitt       1323   1 rt2870sta
```

But `ifconfig` doesn't show any new interface.

Can you point me in the right direction?

---

When I plug in the USB device, `dmesg` shows the following:

```
[ 4514.452959] usb 2-1.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[ 4514.570222] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=3c19
[ 4514.570250] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4514.570256] usb 2-1.3: Product: 11n Adapter
[ 4514.570280] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Ralink
[ 4514.570284] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 4514.570701] usb 2-1.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

---

A little more data.

I checked `ifconfig`, and there's not any wireless adapter detected by debian:

```
# ifconfig
eth0 ...
lo ...
```

The contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
#NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I hope this additional data helps

---

More data

After running `iwconfig`  and `ifconfig -a`  I get the following output:

```
# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
pan0      no wireless extensions.

# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:27:0e:24:c1:4d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.225  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::227:eff:fe24:c14d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1003590 errors:0 dropped:3149 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:485162 errors:857 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:857
          collisions:22136 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1302629169 (1.2 GiB)  TX bytes:31914674 (30.4 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e3200000-e3220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:56406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10194174 (9.7 MiB)  TX bytes:10194174 (9.7 MiB)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2a:c0:d2:a1:be:fa  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

(as you can see, I am connected to a wired network on `eth0`, but I'd like to get rid of the cable ;) )

I assume (though I'm not sure), that `pan0` has something to do with the wireless adapter. Now, if that's right, all that remains is know how to configure it.

Comment: Not running Debian, but perhaps [firmware-ralink (0.35~bpo60+1)](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/kernel/firmware-ralink) might be useful.

Comment: What is `dmesg` saying, when you plug-in usb?

Comment: @week Just updated the post with the data you requested :-)

Comment: It looks like it's detected ok. Now, `modprobe rt2870sta`, then check if it's loaded `lsmod`.

Comment: @week: already done... it's loaded, but the interface does not appear when I call `ifconfig`

Comment: Have you tried `iwconfig` or `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: Hm, I can see why it's not working now, http://wiki.debian.org/rt2870sta , this usb card is not among supported ones. But it's possible, that it might still work, try this procedure http://www.ha19.no/usb/ , simply `modprobe -r rt2870sta`, `modprobe rt2870sta` and `echo 2001 3c18 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2870/new_id` . Hope it will work for you. That pan0 device will probably be bluetooth device. If you manage to get it right `iwconfig` will show you more than `no wireless extension`.

Answer (score 0):

Debian is relatively well documented.

http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi
http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

Install wpa_supplicant and add your network.